Given the row and column of a minified js file, how to find where it is using its source map file?
Not talking about using chrome development tool which seems to require you run your app 1st.
My question is just given the minified file and source map file, no browser, can you find the real function name from row and column number ? then you can go to source and understand the issue.

found it, use this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map
very cool
